# GKTurnBasedMatch invite push notifications?

Tags: ios, push

Does GKTurnBasedMatch send out a *push* notification when you invite a player?

I can't find this answer in the docs or anywhere. I see references to push notifications sent when for each turn, but not invites.

I was expecting them to exist, but wasn't receiving them in the app I'm developing. Before I bang my head against the wall any more, it would be nice to know if they are actually implemented.

If they're *not* implemented, how do players know when they've been invited to a game?

Answer (score 0):

Players get a push notification from game center when it is their turn, not directly upon invitation.

Comment: This makes sense now - like Words With Friends. The first indication you've been invited to a match is your opponent's first move. Thanks!